# Storing User Data iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, keychain, persistent

i'm developing an iPhone app for the first time. I know that username and password commonly stored in KeyChain. How about data like FirstName, ProfilePictureUrl, I got the data from a rest api. Since those data (firstname...) barely changed, i'm thinking to store it somewhere locally. SHould I use KeyChain as well? or SQLLite? XML?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use sqlite to store them in a local database. or NSUserDefault if you are not expecting massive data.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest solution would be to store them in a .plist file

an example tutorial can be found here: http://ipgames.wordpress.com/tutorials/writeread-data-to-plist-file/