# How to work with validating trust of SecCertificateRef

Tags: ios, keychain, x509

I am working with x509 certificates and validating trust of those certificates. I am able to "import" the x509 certificate into a SecCertificateRef object but the concerns I have is with validating trust. This is currently what I have:

```
 SecCertificateRef certificateRef = SecCertificateCreateWithData((CFAllocatorRef)NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef)(x509Certificate));
 SecTrustRef trustRef = nil;
 SecPolicyRef policyRef = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();

 SecTrustResultType trustResultType;
 SecCertificateRef evalCertArray[1] = { certificateRef };

 CFArrayRef cfCertRef = CFArrayCreate ((CFAllocatorRef) NULL,(void *)evalCertArray, 1,&kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);

 OSStatus status1 = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates (cfCertRef, policyRef, &trustRef);    
 OSStatus status2 = SecTrustEvaluate (trustRef, &trustResultType);
```

Now this code will give me a `trustResultType` of `kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure`. When I get this result, I prompt the user if this certificate should be trusted and if the user selects yes, I am executing this code"

```
CFDataRef errDataRef = SecTrustCopyExceptions(trustRef);
SecTrustSetExceptions(trustRef, errDataRef);
SecTrustEvaluate(trustRef, &trustResultType);
```

This should in theory return back a `kSecTrustResultUnspecified` or `kSecTrustResultProceed`. My question is, what would be the best way of remembering this value if I need to check the trust of the same certificate again. Would I ever need to store the modified SecTrustRef (with the exceptions) in the keychain for future use. Or would it be okay to just have a flag linked with that certificate stating this certificate is trusted?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, what would be the best way of remembering this value if I need to check the trust of the same certificate again.

Save user settings with [`NSUserDefault`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html). See, for example, [Storing User Data iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655336/storing-user-data-ios).

---

> Would I ever need to store the modified SecTrustRef (with the exceptions) in the keychain for future use.

Would your user ever need to withdrawal his/her trust?

---

> Or would it be okay to just have a flag linked with that certificate stating this certificate is trusted?

You can store it however you like. It seems to me you need a map of Certificate <-> Status. I imagine a case where a user might want to never trust a certificate, too.

Comment: I see, my main confusion was if I needed to somehow store the SecTrustRef back into the SecCertificateRef. I couldn't find a way to do that, but even if there was, I should probably never modify the actual certificate. Thanks for clearing things up.